# Adding and triggering a transition within on_enter state callback

Tags: pytransitions

I want to store a previous state A when entering state B using a state history. Later 'on_enter' of another state X, add a transition X->A, trigger it and return to state A.

A -> B (store A) -> C -> X (add transition from X to A) -> A

```
from transitions.extensions import HierarchicalGraphMachine


class Matter(HierarchicalGraphMachine):
    def __init__(self, states):
        # self.separator = '/'
        self.history = []
        self.stored = []
        HierarchicalGraphMachine.__init__(
            self,
            states=states,
            initial='root',
            show_state_attributes=True
        )

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self.history[-1]

    @state.setter
    def state(self, value):
        self.history.append(value)

    def store_last(self):
        self.stored.append(self.history[-2])

    def to_stored(self):
        stored = self.stored.pop()
        temp_transition = {
            'trigger': 'jump',
            'source': self.state,
            'dest': stored
        }
        self.add_transition(**temp_transition)
        self.trigger('jump')
        self.remove_transition(**temp_transition)


TRANSITIONS = [
  ['walk', 'standing', 'walking'],
  ['stop', 'walking', 'standing'],
  ['drink', '*', 'caffeinated'],
  ['walk',
   ['caffeinated', 'caffeinated_dithering'],
   'caffeinated_running'],
  ['relax', 'caffeinated', 'standing']
]

STATES = [{
    'name': 'root',
    'initial': 'standing',
    'transitions': TRANSITIONS,
    'children': [
        {
            'name': 'standing',
        },
        {
            'name': 'walking',
            'on_enter': 'store_last',
        },
        {
            'name': 'caffeinated',
            'children': [
                'dithering',
                {
                    'name': 'running',
                    'on_enter': 'to_stored'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

If I run the code skipping `on_enter` the transition is added, triggered and removed as expected.

```
# this works
lump = Matter(states=STATES)
lump.trigger('walk')
assert lump.history == ['root', 'root_standing', 'root_walking']
assert lump.stored == ['root_standing']
lump.trigger('drink')
# set state manually to skip on_enter
lump.state = 'root_caffeinated_running'
# run on_enter method manually works
lump.to_stored()
assert lump.state == 'root_standing'
assert lump.stored == []
assert lump.get_nested_transitions(trigger='jump') == []
lump.get_graph().draw('my_state_diagram.pdf', prog='dot')
```

If I run it within `on_enter` I get an error "MachineError: "Can't trigger event 'jump' from state(s) root_caffeinated_running!"

```
# cannot do the jump using on_enter
lump = Matter(states=STATES)
lump.trigger('walk')
lump.trigger('drink')
lump.trigger('walk')
# Can't trigger event 'jump' from state(s) root_caffeinated_running!
lump.get_graph().draw('my_state_diagram.pdf', prog='dot')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `transitions` will add auto transitions which can be used to reach every state directly without the need to add transitions temporarily. In combination with `Machine.trigger` that can be used to call events by their name, your `to_stored` method could be simplified to:

```py
    def to_stored(self):
        stored = self.stored.pop()
        self.trigger(f"to_{stored}")
```